# GIT utility to generate graph like this?

Tags: git

I am working on an assignment, I need to generate the graph of my git repository like this with arrows

[image]

Is there any utility to generate graph like this? I know about gitg, gitk; But I need a utility through with I can generate a graph in the same format as the one shown in the picture?

Comment: Do you want to see a picture going horizontally from left to right, or is `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` alright with you?

Comment: If this is an assignment, won't the person assigning it to you want you to do it yourself instead of just finding a library that does it for you?

Comment: `gitk`, using the `--all` parameter? It's vertical, but almost the same you are looking for.

Comment: Looks a little like generated with dot. Tools unfortunately I don't know doing this. But looking forward to some too ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer from inside [SE could help here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060886/2915834). It links to an [alias](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Use_graphviz_for_display), which is creating a dot file based on your git repository

Pretty much add:

```
[alias]
        graphviz = "!f() { echo 'digraph git {' ; git log --pretty='format:  %h -> { %p }' \"$@\" | sed 's/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]*/\"&\"/g' ; echo '}'; }; f"
```

to your .git/config. After this, you can run it and create your diagram e.g. with

```
git graphviz HEAD~100..HEAD~60 | dotty /dev/stdin
```

(also token from the link wiki resource). If you just redirect output to a dot-file, you can manually compile the graph on your wishes with dot or maybe neato. Also you can adjust the alias a little for better formatting (color, shape...) of e.g. nodes.